# how to create multi tasking cron job?

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to create a cron job, that create a new file every 06:00 in the morning, giving him a full 644 permission (write&read), and after copy it to a different location.

Do i need to create 2 different cron jobs? one for creating and one for copying? right now i done the copy part (i create the files manually):

```
*/2 * * * * cp -rf /var/www/html/emaillist.txt /home/uview/emaillistforwatch/
```

Comment: i think you can combine both actions in 1 script, just tell the script to first copy the old file to the new directory then let it create/override the old one, but please validate the copy action first before running the create action

Comment: You may add the creating and copying commands in a bash script and use that as your command to run from crontab

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use option "&&", because with option you can run multi tasking in cronjob.

Ex:

```
*/2 * * * * mkdir /var/www/html/test && cp -rf /var/www/html/emaillist.txt /var/www/html/test
```

Or You can create file script and add multi tasking in scirpt. After you can add file scritp in cron run is ok.

Ex:
File test.sh:

```html
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(pwd)
mkdir test
cp test.txt test
echo "done"
```

In cron:

```
*/2 * * * * bash test.sh
```

Comment: What is better or more efficient way? to add && or to write a new script dedicated for the purpose?

Comment: With only a few cases of small services that you use '&&'. But with many cases you want to perform multiple tasks and services, you should create a bash(script .sh) file to perform those tasks.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use both of script and '&&'

the '&&' force your second command that be run after (only after) the first command fully implemented

for example :

```
touch script.sh
chown a+x script.sh
vim script.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   touch /YOUR_FILE_ADDRESS/file.txt && chown 644 /YOUR_FILE_ADDRESS/file.txt && cp /YOUR_FILE_ADDRESS/file.txt /DESTINATION_ADDRESS echo "`date`  done" >> result.log
```

and configure crontab :

```
crontab -e
   0 6 * * *         /SCRIPT_ADDRESS/script.sh
```